# Autonomous GPS navigation issues

Tags: gps, error, navigation

I am trying to achieve autonomous GPS navigation on my RC car. I am using a very high quality GNSS/INS sensor (Advanced Navigation Spatial), from which I am getting lat, long and heading values. The sensor is connected to a Raspberry Pi from which its data is parsed using their special protocol and then passed to Arduino Mega via serial using ROS.

I have a route made out of picked waypoints from Google Maps. I am using Haversine distance and bearing formulas, from there I determine which direction to turn the servo and when to move to the next waypoint.

The vehicle follows the route, but sways around a lot. There are also problematic waypoints at which the vehicle just goes crazy and looks like it's getting +-5 meters error. Funnily enough I observed the output of the sensor through their software whilst driving the vehicle, and the path it followed looked smooth without any anomalies, with an error margin of +-0.25m.

At this point I am not what the problem is. Is it the sensor, my code or RC car itself (maybe something to do with steering)?

Here's the minimal version of my Arduino Sketch:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define STEERING_ADDITION 12

#define NEUTRAL 94
#define LEFT (NEUTRAL+STEERING_ADDITION)
#define RIGHT (NEUTRAL-STEERING_ADDITION)

//#define BEARING_THRESHOLD 3.5
#define BEARING_THRESHOLD 2.5
#define DISTANCE_THRESHOLD 0.5

#define NUMBER_OF_WAYPOINTS 23

Servo myservo;

ros::NodeHandle nh;

float gps_current[3];
float gps_target[NUMBER_OF_WAYPOINTS][2] = {
{xxx, xxx},
{xxx, xxx}, ....

};

void messageCb(const std_msgs::Float32MultiArray& msg) {
    gps_current[0] = msg.data[0]; //Lat
    gps_current[1] = msg.data[1]; //Long
    gps_current[2] = msg.data[2]; //Heading
}

int waypoint = 0;

float required_bearing = 0;
float rel_bearing = 0;

float dist = 0;

bool navigation = true;

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray> sub("gps", &messageCb );

void setup() {
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    nh.initNode();
    nh.subscribe(sub);
    myservo.attach(9);
 }

 void loop() {


 required_bearing = bearing(gps_current[0], gps_current[1], 
 gps_target[waypoint][0], gps_target[waypoint][1]);
 rel_bearing = required_bearing - gps_current[2]

 dist = distance(gps_current[0], gps_current[1], gps_target[waypoint][0], 
 gps_target[waypoint][1]);

 if(dist < DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    waypoint++;
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    delay(100);
 }
 else {
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
 }

    if (navigation) {

        if(rel_bearing < -BEARING_THRESHOLD) {
            myservo.write(RIGHT);
        }
        else if(rel_bearing > BEARING_THRESHOLD) {
            myservo.write(LEFT);
        }
        else {
            myservo.write(NEUTRAL);
        }
    }


    nh.spinOnce();
}


float bearing(float lat1,float lon1,float lat2,float lon2) {

float teta1 = radians(lat1);
float teta2 = radians(lat2);
float delta1 = radians(lat2-lat1);
float delta2 = radians(lon2-lon1);

//==================Heading Formula Calculation================//

float y = sin(delta2) * cos(teta2);
float x = cos(teta1)*sin(teta2) - sin(teta1)*cos(teta2)*cos(delta2);
float brng = atan2(y,x);
brng = degrees(brng);// radians to degrees
brng = ( ((int)brng + 360) % 360 ); 

return brng;


}

float distance(float flat1, float flon1, float flat2, float flon2) {

float dist_calc=0;
float dist_calc2=0;
float diflat=0;
float diflon=0;

//I've to spplit all the calculation in several steps. If i try to do it in a single line the arduino will explode.
diflat=radians(flat2-flat1);
flat1=radians(flat1);
flat2=radians(flat2);
diflon=radians((flon2)-(flon1));

dist_calc = (sin(diflat/2.0)*sin(diflat/2.0));
dist_calc2= cos(flat1);
dist_calc2*=cos(flat2);
dist_calc2*=sin(diflon/2.0);
dist_calc2*=sin(diflon/2.0);
dist_calc +=dist_calc2;

dist_calc=(2*atan2(sqrt(dist_calc),sqrt(1.0-dist_calc)));

dist_calc*=6371000.0; //Converting to meters

return dist_calc;
}
```

I have double checked the values I am getting on Arduino and they are identical to the ones that are being sent from the sensor, so no data is being corrupted.

Comment: Is your GPS using Dual Frequency L1 and L5? not many products have this yet (July 2018). see https://medium.com/@sjbarbeau/dual-frequency-gnss-on-android-devices-152b8826e1c (the xiaomi mi 8 on sale does have this can can get sub <10cm )

Comment: @Mapperz, it's L1 only, http://www.advancednavigation.com.au/product/spatial. What I don't get is why I get so much swaying around when the error in their Manager Utility is only 0.25m?

Comment: Remember you RC is needing large accuracy a few cm, will make changes to it course http://www.advancednavigation.com.au/sites/default/files/product_documents/spatial_performance_evaluation.pdf  still experiences gps drift (look up it and most Pokemon players experience this problem from a smartphone of over 100m in some cases).

Comment: Try and find a sensor with the broadcom chipset (BCM47755) https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/gnss-gps-socs/bcm47755 then you can compare the accuaracy.

Comment: @Mapperz, thank you for you reply! How can one minimize GPS drift? I have noticed that couple of times, lat, long and heading are drifting when the unit is stationary.

Comment: @Mapperz, what's so special about the BCM47755?

Comment: Broadcom releases world’s first dual-Frequency GNSS Receiver https://galileognss.eu/broadcom-releases-worlds-first-dual-frequency-gnss-receiver/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80511/discussion-between-mapperz-and-hypomania).